# Property validation failure - Cloudformation Template for AWS::Cognito::UserPool

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I keep getting a `Property validation failure` error in cloudformation when I run my `AWS::Cognito::UserPool` resource template. Here's how the scripts look like

```
Resources:
  ESRVCognitoUserPool:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-CognitoUserPool'
      AdminCreateUserConfig: 
        AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: 'True'
      UserPoolTags: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}'
      Schema:
        - Name: 'country_code'
          AttributeDataType: 'String'
          Mutable: 'true'
          Required: 'false'
          DeveloperOnlyAttribute: 'false'
          StringAttributeConstraints: 
            MaxLength: '2048'
            MinLength: '1'
        - Name: "contact_id"
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: 'true'
          Required: 'false'
          DeveloperOnlyAttribute: 'false'
          StringAttributeConstraints: 
            MaxLength: '2048'
            MinLength: '1'
        - Name: "language"
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: 'true'
          Required: 'false'
          DeveloperOnlyAttribute: 'false'
          StringAttributeConstraints: 
            MaxLength: '256'
            MinLength: '1'
        - Name: "account_id"
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: 'true'
          Required: 'false'
          DeveloperOnlyAttribute: 'false'
          StringAttributeConstraints: 
            MaxLength: '2048'
            MinLength: '1'
        - Name: "tracking_id"
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: 'true'
          Required: 'false'
          DeveloperOnlyAttribute: 'false'
          StringAttributeConstraints: 
            MaxLength: '256'
            MinLength: '1'
Outputs:
  StackName:
    Description: 'Stack name.'
    Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}'
  UserPoolInfo:
    Description: 'UserPool Information'
    Value: !Ref ESRVCognitoUserPool
    Export:
      Name: UserPool-ID
```

I'd appreciate any tips.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Hi @Marcin. I just get `Property Validation Failure` without any other information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-userpooltags) UserPoolTags is of JSON type. You aren't allowed to pass a simple string to it.

See this [question](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-userpooltags) on how to properly pass a value.